# eclipse open java file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently upgraded my ubuntu installation to 14.04 and can't open the source of runtime types anymore.

In my eclipse I have set the jre to the openjdk 7 installation, which should contain the source (which worked before the upgrade). But when I open for example `java.lang.String` I get only the bytecode view.

What could be wrong?

Markus

Comment: You have to attach manually the `src.zip` from the JDK to Eclipse

Comment: Really? I never needed before. I'll give it a try...

Comment: Yes. Check [this](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/07/14/3-ways-of-jdk-source-code-attachment-in-eclipse/) out.

Comment: Great, worked! I was struggling with this a bit: http://shortrecipes.blogspot.de/2013/07/ubuntu-install-java-7-source-openjdk-7.html